# Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I've just create a new spring boot project and I have a problem in the pom.xml and I have no idea how to resolve it, please someone help.

this is my pom.xml
i got an error in first line.
"Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 
 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or 
 updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.22.2 
 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled."

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.amol.student.dal</groupId>
 <artifactId>studentdal</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>studentdal</name>
 <description>Student DAL</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Behind proxy/firewall ?

Comment: what proxy/ firewall? i don't know anything about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete folder maven-surefire-plugin from location ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins. And rigth click on project -> Maven-> update project.

Answer (score 1):

Go on the top, menu bar, then click on Run > Run As > Maven Install and let the process be complete, after that,
Now right click on pom.xml file > maven > update project.

After struggling for 1.5 hours, These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

@Rishikesh Chaudhari answer is correct, before you delete folder "maven-surefire-plugin" make sure that you are in a network that can access and download dependencies from the maven repository. The IDE will download the dependency for you when you update your project(click on project name>Maven>Update project)